# output of sudo -l confusing me

Tags: shell, sudo, sudoers

(habdbsync) NOPASSWD: ALL, (habdbsync) !/bin/sh, !/bin/ksh, !/bin/csh, !/bin/tcsh, !/bin/zsh, 
!/bin/bash, (habdbsync) !/bin/su,

```
(habdbsync) !/usr/bin/ssh, !/usr/bin/scp, !/usr/bin/slogin

(root) /bin/chown habdbsync /devbuild/*
(root) /bin/chown -R root\:root /devbuild/*
(root) /bin/chown root\:root /devbuild/*
(root) /bin/true
```

What each statement means ?

Comment: `sudo -ll` gives a more expanded output, which may help to explain the entries. My output is a lot different, so I cannot interpret your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line means that you cannot run any of the shells listed, nor `su`, as user `habdbsync`.

The second line means that you cannot run `ssh`, `scp`, or `slogin` as user `habdbsync`.

Note that in both the above, the exlamation mark (`!`) is a `not` operator.

The next four lines allow you to run the commands listed, but only as user `root`.  Note that the commands also have arguments that need to match.  Therefore you can run:

```
/bin/chown habdbsync /devbuild/*
```

as `root` with `sudo`, but not:

```
/bin/chown habdbsync /*
```